# How can I start up Windows without explorer loading up?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-explorer, kiosk

What I'm looking to do is to start it up, then have it load IE in kiosk mode.

The IE part is easy, (-k) but I'm looking to find out how I can get the computer to start up without explorer.

I've heard its as simple as changing a registry entry.  Any clues?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without explorer"?

Comment: uhhh.. not there?  The same thing as if you were to go into task manager and shut it off..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following registry key to change the shell that is started on bootup:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
Shell"="explorer.exe"
```

However, I recommend you read [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/28631/how-can-i-prevent-explorer-starting-as-a-shell-in-a-kiosk-setting) which addresses the same issue and has some good insights.

Comment: Yup. Thats the way..

Comment: FYI, as a follow up:  http://superuser.com/questions/108265/how-do-you-replace-the-logon-shell-with-iexplore