# How do you replace the logon shell with iexplore?

Tags: windows, shell, kiosk

This is related to my previous question. Apparently I didn't know what [I thought I knew..](https://superuser.com/questions/107611/how-can-i-start-up-windows-without-explorer-loading-up)

Like said in my last post, I am looking to make a kiosk where when it starts up, it goes straight into **iexplore** without loading up explorer.exe.

I set the current logon shell to iexplore, but that didn't work.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon] Shell"="iexplore.exe"

perhaps somebody could help me back on track?

Comment: You should elaborate the "didn't work" part: some error message? incorrect behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, that can't work unless you add the path to iexplore.exe to the environment variables, or change the value of '**Shell**' to:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
```

you may have to press **ctrl + alt + del** to logon.

Answer (score 4):

According [microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B555463&x=18&y=10) the value should be `iexplore -k http://www.yoursite.com`

And maybe [autologon](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B315231&x=7&y=13) could help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that should just work.
The only step you are missing is automatically logging in.

Though, if you want to go for a secure kiosk solution, try [SteadyState](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/sharedaccess/seeit/internetcafe.mspx), it's free.

Why didn't [How can I prevent explorer starting as a shell in a kiosk setting](https://serverfault.com/questions/28631/how-can-i-prevent-explorer-starting-as-a-shell-in-a-kiosk-setting) help?

Comment: i forgot to note that I'm using win xp embedded. (I am testing it by logging off & logging on)

what I get when I log on is (after logging in, working on that next) is a blank screen.  Explorer didn't load, as expected, but IE doesn't either

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off trying to load something like Firefox. iexplore and explorer are very tightly interwoven.